# Create a Border Around a View in Xamarin iOS Designer?

Tags: ios, xamarin

Is there an equivalent to Xcode Storyboard > Identity Inspector > User Defined Runtime Attributes > 'layer.borderWidth' ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember ever seeing something to define a border width or color in the Xamarin iOS Designer. I guess you're gonna have to use this.View.Layer.BorderWidth in your UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Studio, right-click Main.storyboard > Open With > Xcode Interface Builder.

Define your Runtime Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the View.Layers to add border color and width.  Since only some of my views will have borders I created an View override and I call it and pass parameters.

```
   public BorderedView(System.Drawing.RectangleF frame, UIColor borderColor, 
  UIViewController vw) : base(frame)
    {
        this.parent = vw;
        _bordercolor = borderColor;
        this.Layer.BorderWidth = 12f;
        this.Layer.Frame = new CGRect(0f, -10f, Frame.Width, Frame.Height + 
  10);
        this.CreateBorder();
        this.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        this.ClipsToBounds = true;
        this.Add(new CircitCustomNavBar().CustomNavMenuView(borderColor, 
  this.parent));
    }

    private void CreateBorder()
    {
        // MasksToBounds == false allows the shadow to appear outside the 
  UIView frame
        this.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        this.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;
        this.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
        this.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
        this.Layer.ShadowRadius = 6.0f;
        this.Layer.ShadowOffset = new System.Drawing.SizeF(0f, 3f);
        this.Layer.BorderColor = _bordercolor.CGColor;


    }
```